# How can I implement a global int/counter across my whole application?

Tags: c#

This may be obvious to someone else, I've wrestled with it for hours to no avail.

How can I implement a global int/counter across my whole application?

It's just one int I need and it would only ever increase.
The counter would be called asynchronously from a few different methods in different classes that are all contributing to the same JSon output from a webApi. 
There are lots of small chunks of data that need a unique id attached to them.

Hope this makes sense. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sounds not good idea from an OOP perspective. What is this variable for? Is it a counter of stored objects? Then you should consider create some kind of collection for those elements.

Comment: I assume that this is for debugging purpose. Therefore I'd go with this: Create a class that works like integer and also has a counter and in every part of your code you use another type that is either set to your class when debugging or to integer when not.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static Global
{
    private static int _counter = 0;
    private static readonly object _lockObject = new object();
    public static void Increment()
    {
        lock (_lockObject) {
            _counter++;
        }
    }
    public static int Counter
    {
        get
        {
            lock (lockObject) {
                return _counter;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static class Global 
{
    private static int counter = 0;
    public static int Counter
    {
         get
         {
             return Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
         {
    }
}
```